# Picture placement in background in 1:2 flex react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to make a section of a page (About us) where the picture takes up 1/3 of the screen and the writing takes up the other 2/3rd of the space in a screen of height- 91vh. However, the image is getting super enlarged when I am trying to do it and the writing comes below it.

About.js

```
return (
        <div id="about" className="style-about">
            <div className="style-picture">
              <img src={picture1}></img>
            </div>
            <div className="style-info">
              <h1 className="style-about-heading"> About Us. </h1>
              <div className="style-paragraph-container">
                ...//Content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

about.css

```
.style-about {
    background-color:#b2c5b2;
    min-height: 91vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.style-picture {
    flex: 1;
}

.style-info {
    flex: 2;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting - width, height for the image ?

Comment: Yes, but it does not align properly -  it is still big